# How to clone object in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, clone

The [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#clone) describes cloning only in accessing Java and in enum class. In latter case clone is just throwing an exception.

So, how would I / should I clone arbitrary Kotlin object?

Should I just use `clone()` as in Java?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

For a `data class`, you can use the compiler-generated [`copy()` method](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#copying). Note that it will perform a shallow copy.

To create a copy of a collection, use the `toList()` or `toSet()` methods, depending on the collection type you need. These methods always create a new copy of a collection; they also perform a shallow copy.

For other classes, there is no Kotlin-specific cloning solution. You can use `.clone()` if it suits your requirements, or build a different solution if it doesn't.

Comment: How can I clone list? For example `List<String>`

Comment: @Dims, you can do that just by using an extension on Iterable<T> toList() or toMutableList().

Comment: @yole: Is it documented/guaranteed that `toSet()` returns a new instance? That does seem to be how it is currently implemented, but the [library docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-set.html) say only that it returns a Set. I'm a little hesitant to depend on this behavior if it isn't part of the library contract.

Answer (score 40):

You can use [Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert the original object to a String and then convert back that String to an actual Object type, and you'll have a clone. Although this is not the intended usage of the Gson library which is actually used to convert between JSON and other object types, but I have devised this method to solve the cloning problem in many of my Kotlin based Android applications.
See my example. Put this function in the class/model of which you want to create a clone. In my example I'm cloning an **Animal** type object so I'll put it in the **Animal** class

```
class Animal{
 fun clone(): Animal 
 {
   val stringAnimal = Gson().toJson(this, Animal::class.java)
   return Gson().fromJson<Animal>(stringAnimal, Animal::class.java)
 }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
val originalAnimal = Animal()
val clonedAnimal = originalAnimal.clone()
```

Comment: This is not a beautiful approach, but is the only it work for me.

Comment: @OsvelAlvarezJacomino This will work for most of your use cases

Comment: I know it will work for most of cases, but i don't like to add external libraries just to avoid shallow copies. In my case, I need to use Gson for other things in code, that's why I decided to used it.

Comment: Ya true. Until we have a better inbuilt solution in Kotlin, this will do as a work-around

Comment: Nice, approach for complex views

Comment: Oh god, please don't do this, ever. It comes with a *MASSIVE* overhead.

Comment: @AgostonHorvath or anyone, did you run a **performance test** in a loop to deep copy objects of a certain size, say 1Kb, using the JSON serialization/deserialization vs the painful (to write) manual override of `clone()`?

Comment: @PauloMerson you can find a recent performance test here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks ; gson would be about twice as slow as the slowest performer in that test, with having to do both serialization and deserialization. And yes, the overhead can be as high as 100x slower!

Comment: Be very careful with this method, because JSON fields and Java classes are not always equivalent, or the serialization itself may make subtle changes to your data. E.g. encountered a situation just now where Gson removed milliseconds from Date objects.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use something like https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo library instead of json? At least should be more efficient

Answer (score 37):

A Kotlin `data class` is easy to clone using `.copy()`

All values will be shallow copied, be sure to handle any list/array contents carefully.

A useful feature of `.copy()` is the ability to change any of the values at copy time. With this class:

```
data class MyData(
    val count: Int,
    val peanuts: Int?,
    val name: String
)
val data = MyData(1, null, "Monkey")
```

You could set values for any of the properties

```
val copy = data.copy(peanuts = 100, name = "Elephant")
```

The result in `copy` would have values `(1, 100, "Elephant")`

Answer (score 9):

If the class you are trying to clone does not implement `Cloneable` or is not a data class and is a part of an outside library, you can create an extension method that returns a new instance. For example:

```
class Person {
  var id: String? = null
  var name: String? = null
} 
fun Person.clone(): Person {
  val person = Person()
  person.id = id
  person.name = name
  return person 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It requires to implement Cloneable for your class then override clone() as a public like:

```
public override fun clone(): Any {<your_clone_code>}
```

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-use-cloneable/2364/3

Answer (score 4):

```
fun <T : Any> clone (obj: T): T {
  if (!obj::class.isData) {
    println(obj)
    throw Error("clone is only supported for data classes")
  }

  val copy = obj::class.memberFunctions.first { it.name == "copy" }
  val instanceParam = copy.instanceParameter!!
  return copy.callBy(mapOf(
    instanceParam to obj
  )) as T
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but it doesn't seem to compile. I'm guessing that something changed in the Kotlin reflection API?

I copy-pasted this verbatim into my code and it resulted in a compilation error: `Unresolved reference: memberFunctions`

Comment: It looks like you have to add `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect` to your dependencies in order to use reflection. However, I tried that and I still got the same error. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if something broke upstream.

Answer (score 2):

I've voted for @yole for nice answer, but other ways if you don't (or can't) use data class. You can write helper method like this:

```
object ModelHelper {

    inline fun <reified T : Serializable> mergeFields(from: T, to: T) {
        from::class.java.declaredFields.forEach { field ->
            val isLocked = field.isAccessible
            field.isAccessible = true
            field.set(to, field.get(from))
            field.isAccessible = isLocked
        }
    }

}
```

So you can "copy" instance A into B by:

```
val bInstance = AClassType()
ModelHelper.mergeFields(aInstance, bInstance)
```

Sometimes, I use this way to merge data from many instances into one object which value available (not null).

Comment: Yes, sometimes we cannot use `data class`es, if make them `abstract` or `open`. How do you think, will this code compile in Android `release` build (it doesn't like reflection).

Comment: This is good, but has a bug. If a field is `null` in `from` it is not copied to `to` (therefore keeping the original, possibly not `null`, value). The fix is to remove the `if`.

Comment: @acdcjunior Yes, you are right. I just remove the if statement. I use if statement because API issue in my teamates, sometime not response data sometime have data, so I catch all data if available and save into local database, if not, null will override data 

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for the fix!

Comment: @CoolMind I applied for company projects, and there apps available on the playstore. But I think this way is not recommended because reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a consistent solution that works for any object type:

Kotlin's Array data structure provides a [clone()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-enum/clone.html) method that can be used to clone the contents of the array:

```
val a = arrayOf(1)
//Prints one object reference
println(a)     
//Prints a different object reference
println(a.clone())
```

As of Kotlin 1.3, the clone method has been supported on all major targets, so it should be usable across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to clone an object using `kotlinx.serialization`

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonConfiguration

@Serializable
class A
{
    val name: String = "Cloneable class A"

    fun clone(): A {
        val json = Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable)
        val jsonStr = json.stringify(serializer(), this)
        return json.parse(serializer(), jsonStr)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just beware that JSON serialization/deserialization loses date and timestamp typing.

Answer (score 0):

Collection copying functions, such as toList(), toMutableList(), toSet() and others, create a snapshot of a collection at a specific moment. Their result is a new collection of the same elements. If you add or remove elements from the original collection, this won't affect the copies. Copies may be changed independently of the source as well.

```
val alice = Person("Alice")
val sourceList = mutableListOf(alice, Person("Bob"))
val copyList = sourceList.toList()
sourceList.add(Person("Charles"))
alice.name = "Alicia"
println("First item's name is: ${sourceList[0].name} in source and ${copyList[0].name} in copy")
println("List size is: ${sourceList.size} in source and ${copyList.size} in copy")
First item's name is: Alicia in source and Alicia in copy
List size is: 3 in source and 2 in copy
```

[Kotlin Official Document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/constructing-collections.html#copy)

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzMCb.png)