# Clone a object in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have migrated my application from Java to Kotlin. In Java, the copying was working just fine. However, when migrated to Kotline it was not working. After that, I came to know about copy method in Kotlin

I have tied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053432/how-to-clone-object-in-kotlin), but it seems I am doing something wrong.

Here is my function :

```
fun updateSwitchState(deviceName: String, switchNumber: Int): AuraSwitch? {
    val singleDevice = Switch()
    for (c in FourNodeDevice) {
        if (deviceName == c.name) {
            val copyDevice : SwitchClone = SwitchClone(c.state, c.name)
            val state = copyDevice.copy(state = copyDevice.state)
            state.updateState(switchNumber)
            singleDevice.state = state.state
            return singleDevice
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Whenever I change data in object `state` in updateState Method the value in object `c` also gets changed. Any help will be useful

Comment: can your show code in java?

Comment: In Java, I made a copy constructor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `copy()` did not solve my purpose. However `clone()` did. I added the following line in my code and it worked as I desired.

```
val state = c.states.clone()
```

Answer (score 1):

You never create a copy of a `state` object.

This call creates another SwitchClone with values identical to `copyDevice` itself.

```
val state = copyDevice.copy(state = copyDevice.state)
```

`copy()` only creates a shallow copy, which means all of your objects, in that case `c`, `copyDevice` and `state` point to the same `c.state`.

You need to explicitly create a deep copy (depending on what properties are mutable) of state object and assign it to `copyDevice.state` field.

Comment: Ohh I see, I thought the same as my value in object C was also changing. Any idea how can I make a deep copy of object in kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin when using the Kotlin Data Class `data class` you get a function called  `copy()` for you. But If your Class is not a `Data Class` and your project has `Gson` and you want to copy the whole object ( probably edit after getting it ), Then if all those conditions are true then this is a solution. This is also a DeepCopy. ( For a data Class you can use the function [`copy()`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#copying)).

Then if you are using `Gson` in your project. Add the function `copy()`:

```
class YourClass () {

// Your class other stuffs here

  fun copy(): YourClass { //Get another instance of YourClass with the values like this!
      val json = Gson().toJson(this)
      return Gson().fromJson(json, YourClass::class.java)
  }
}
```

If you want to install Gson then get the [latest version here](https://github.com/google/gson).